# Can I calculate the mean/mode of a variable (by another variable) and tabulate in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, mean, tabulate

I want to find the mean (for numerical variables) and mode (for character variables) for each of the variables under column "trait_name" for each unique "taxon_name". I would then like to tabulate these values.

This is what my dataframe looks like currently (I also have a wide version):

[image: current dataframe]

This is my desired output:
[image: goal]

I've written code that manually calculates the mean and mode for each "trait_name" per "taxon_name" as follows:

```
# create mode function
find.mode <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
  
  if(na.rm){ 
    x = x[!is.na(x)]
  }
  
  val <- unique(x)
  return(val[which.max(tabulate(match(x, val)))])
}


# MEAN AND MODE OF TRAITS
## Acacia implexa 
acacia_mass <- mean(species_traits_wide$seed_dry_mass[species_traits_wide$taxon_name == "Acacia implexa"], na.rm = TRUE)
acacia_length <- mean(species_traits_wide$seed_length[species_traits_wide$taxon_name == "Acacia implexa"], na.rm = TRUE)
acacia_form <- find.mode(species_traits_wide$plant_growth_form[species_traits_wide$taxon_name == "Acacia implexa"])
acacia_dormancy <- find.mode(species_traits_wide$seed_dormancy_class[species_traits_wide$taxon_name == "Acacia implexa"])
acacia_treatment <- find.mode(species_traits_wide$seed_germination_treatment[species_traits_wide$taxon_name == "Acacia implexa"])
```

But I need to automate the process for all species in the dataframe/any new species I wish to add

```
df <- structure(list(...1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 
93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 
107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 
120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 
133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 
146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 
159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 
172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 
185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 
198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 
211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 
224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 
237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 
250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 
263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 
276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 
289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 
302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 
315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 
328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 
341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 
354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 
367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 
380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 
393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 
406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 
419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 
432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 
445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 451), taxon_name = c("Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", "Acacia implexa", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Casuarina cunninghamiana", 
"Casuarina cunninghamiana", "Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", 
"Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", 
"Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", 
"Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", 
"Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", 
"Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", 
"Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", 
"Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", 
"Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", 
"Eucalyptus viminalis", "Eucalyptus viminalis", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", 
"Hardenbergia violacea", "Hardenbergia violacea", "Themeda triandra", 
"Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", 
"Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", 
"Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", 
"Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", 
"Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", 
"Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", 
"Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", 
"Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", 
"Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", 
"Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", 
"Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", 
"Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", 
"Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", "Themeda triandra", 
"Themeda triandra"), plant_growth_form = c("tree", "shrub", "tree", 
NA, NA, "tree", NA, NA, NA, NA, "tree", NA, NA, "shrub tree", 
NA, "tree", NA, "tree", "tree", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "shrub tree", 
"shrub tree", "tree", "tree", "tree", "tree", "tree", "tree", 
"tree", "tree", NA, NA, NA, NA, "tree", NA, NA, "tree", "tree", 
"tree", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "tree", "tree", "tree", "tree", "tree", 
NA, "tree", "tree", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "tree", NA, "tree", "tree", "tree", "tree", "tree", "tree", 
"tree", "tree", "tree", NA, NA, "climber_herbaceous", "climber", 
"climber", "climber_herbaceous", "climber", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "climber_herbaceous", NA, NA, "climber", "shrub", NA, 
"subshrub", "shrub", "shrub", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "subshrub", "subshrub", "climber_woody", "climber_herbaceous herb subshrub", 
"climber", "climber", NA, "climber", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "tussock", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"graminoid", "tussock", NA, "herb", "graminoid herb", "herb", 
NA, "graminoid herb", "graminoid herb", "graminoid", "herb", 
"graminoid", "graminoid", "graminoid herb", "tussock", "graminoid", 
"tussock", "tussock"), seed_dormancy_class = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "physical_dormancy", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "non_dormant", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "physical_dormancy", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), seed_dry_mass = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13.9712, 17.8, 19.84, 22.86, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 28.39, NA, NA, NA, 11.14, 10.14, 11.12, 9.92, 9.78, 
11.2, 8.816, 11.012, 8.72, 10.428, 6.088, 9.164, 10.14, 9.876, 
8.632, 9.068, 9.86, 8.328, 8.196, 5, 9.36, 9.104, 9.504, 8.76, 
9.152, 9.036, 8.276, 9.744, 9.296, 10.04, 10.232, 10.616, 8.712, 
9.364, 8.608, 10.736, 6.164, 7.672, 7.98, 6.564, 7.644, 9.552, 
10.344, 10.976, 7.376, 8.924, 8.484, 7.812, 7.172, 8.268, 7.012, 
9.416, 5.904, 10.14, 7.66, 7.92, 9.688, 10.2, 6.008, 8.872, 7.788, 
6.448, 7.416, 10.612, 6.808, 8.4, 7.716, 8.268, 10.12, 7.92, 
7.84, 5.78, 8.956, 7.852, 9.644, 7.296, 7.484, 6.832, 5.752, 
7.064, 10.268, 6.752, 9.276, 4.82, 7.284, 8.304, 7.944, 6.936, 
7.148, 7.864, 8.172, 6.22, 8.372, 8.6, 8.932, 6.592, 6.54, 5.784, 
5.88, 6.164, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.26, 
0.631, 1.59, 3.81, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.6698, 0.7136, 0.8638, 
0.6398, 0.6592, 0.738, 0.5688, 0.89, 0.8054, 0.5736, 0.9084, 
0.7104, 0.735, 0.7226, 0.6748, 0.742, 0.8002, 0.916, 0.7606, 
0.5774, 0.595, 0.6756, 0.7222, 0.9476, 0.8242, 0.6502, 0.4944, 
0.6392, 0.8068, 0.6578, 0.6546, 0.5928, 0.7562, 0.7618, 0.6378, 
0.7154, 0.8028, 0.3886, 0.7974, 0.6492, 0.5052, 0.7518, 0.7036, 
0.5704, 0.8062, 0.777, 0.7558, 0.6666, 0.6418, 0.848, 0.5736, 
0.3088, 0.7134, 0.5522, 0.7382, 0.9686, 0.3278, 0.718, 0.5976, 
0.5234, 0.4762, 0.456, 0.5732, 0.3338, 0.523, 0.8498, 0.3254, 
0.4948, 0.514, 0.256, 0.5336, 0.3958, 0.5152, 0.4308, 0.409, 
0.552, 0.466, 0.4842, 0.5292, 0.339, 0.2946, 0.4286, 0.2836, 
0.3872, 0.2828, 0.5202, 0.3278, 0.4602, 0.349, 0.3206, 0.471, 
0.2248, 0.3384, 0.49, 0.6982, 0.3084, 0.3388, 0.4416, 0.7154, 
0.8142, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.55, 0.6036, 0.6352, 
0.67, 0.7312, 1.06, 1.1, 2.79, 2.86, 7.83, 150, 173, 600, NA, 
0.731, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 22.303, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 12.371, 12.728, 13.3904, 22, 26.3788, 29.6068, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 35.03, NA, NA, NA, NA, 25.4, 20, 20.6, 11.4, 
24.8, 18.8, 25.8, 9, 18.2, 19.8, 15.4, 16.7, 17.1, 10.8, 22.6, 
18.1, 15.1, 19.7, 9.5, 8.7, 11.7, 22.4, 15.5, 22.5, 18.4, 16.1, 
15.7, 20.8, 19.7, 19.4, 24.2, 19.4, 23.8, 17, 14.5, 24.9, 14.2, 
21.8, 9.9, 20.1, 20.1, 19.4, 23.6, 18.2, 14, 11.4, 18.7, 14.8, 
10.7, 19.5, 18.6, 19.1, 21, 25, 24, 19, 17.8, 17.2, 22.9, 16.6, 
17.9, 16.5, 13.9, 12.6, 20.6, 15.6, 18.3, 20.6, 18.1, 5, 5.7, 
18.8, 19.9, 18, 19.9, 17.4, 18.1, 22.1, 12.4, 23.5, 18.9, 8.4, 
16, 17.7, 16.2, 19.6, 23.5, 9.6, 10.9, 6.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 39.64, NA, 3.36, 39, 3.2, NA, 4.11, 4.5879, 2.1436, 3.79, 
2.9, NA, 3.85, NA, 1.6, 1.8, 1.975, 2, 2.2, 2.4, 2.8, 3, 3.2, 
3.4, 4, 5.6, 2.4, 2.5, 2.63625, 2.7, 3.136, 3.4544, 4.0384, 4.3856, 
4.5108, 4.7688, 5.1824, 5.25, NA, NA, 2.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), seed_germination_treatment = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "heat scarify", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "heat", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "smoke", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), seed_length = c(NA, NA, NA, 
4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 5, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1.97, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
5.15, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.71, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 
5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.99, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -451L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    ...1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
    )), taxon_name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), plant_growth_form = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), seed_dormancy_class = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), seed_dry_mass = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), seed_germination_treatment = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), seed_length = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x136a0dac0>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi Paige! Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you edit your question and include the output of `dput(df)`? Thanks!

Comment: maybe the wide format, if you could :-)

Comment: upload a copy of my dataframe file (wide format)?

Comment: yes exactly. You can do so by calling dput() on the dataframe!

Comment: I'm struggling with dput but I have written .csv for both long and wide formats of my data. where do I upload these?

Comment: oh I guess you could put it onto dropbox or google drive or something idk! Also pastebin.com would work

Comment: @Mark added the drive link to the post

Comment: I added it to your question! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

# mode function is taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45216553/4145280 - thanks to C8H10N4O2!
get_mode <- function(x, return_multiple = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE) {
  if(na.rm){
    x <- na.omit(x)
  }
  ux <- unique(x)
  freq <- tabulate(match(x, ux))
  mode_loc <- if(return_multiple) which(freq==max(freq)) else which.max(freq)
  return(ux[mode_loc])
}

# across all of the columns after taxon_name, check if it's a number column. If yes, get the mean, removing NAs (note: if you don't want to do this, or it's not appropriate for the data, you can remove this). If no, then get the mode (removing NAs too)
df |> summarise(across(-c(...1), ~ ifelse(is.numeric(.), as.character(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)),get_mode(., na.rm = TRUE))), .by = taxon_name)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 6
  taxon_name               plant_growth_form seed_dormancy_class seed_dry_mass  
  <chr>                    <chr>             <chr>               <chr>          
1 Acacia implexa           tree              physical_dormancy   8.967897142857…
2 Casuarina cunninghamiana tree              non_dormant         0.632023076923…
3 Eucalyptus viminalis     tree              NA                  67.32578571428…
4 Hardenbergia violacea    climber           physical_dormancy   18.04795959595…
5 Themeda triandra         tussock           NA                  4.375857352941…
# ℹ 2 more variables: seed_germination_treatment <chr>, seed_length <chr>
```

Comment: wow, perfect, how incredible! can I convert that tibble output to a dataframe?

Comment: tibbles *are* dataframes! but if you're wanting the base R dataframe, then you can use as.data.frame() on it! :-)

Comment: you made it look so easy. thanks a bunch for teaching me something new. super grateful!

Comment: is there a way to apply the mode function here that outputs a value other than NA for species with only one value under a trait name? For example, one of my species is once listed as "physical_dormancy" but when I apply your summarise() function it returns NA (I think because mode needs more than 1 value?). Any help appreciated! @Mark

Comment: hmmm I don't know if I follow! In the sample input dataframe, there are two rows with the seed dormancy class physical_dormancy, and neither has any NAs

Comment: Sorry - I added more species to the dataframe @Mark

Comment: I used the current one @ecologist8112, there's only two physical_dormancy rows. You can check by searching for physical_dormancy on this webpage